# Error in creating Customer Community User

Tags: user, customer-community, nforce

I am trying to create a community user programmatically using the nforce node.js wrapper library. I'm running this as sysadmin privilege. This is what I am using:

```
var user = nforce.createSObject('User', {
        LastName: "Chen2",
        FirstName: "Andy2",
        Alias: "ac2",
        Username: "hello@gmail.com",
        Email: "hello@gmail.com",
        ProfileId: "00e36000000YIZ6AAO", // ProfileId for Customer Community User
        CommunityNickname: "nickname2",
        TimeZoneSidKey: "America/New_York",
        LocaleSidKey: "en_US",
        EmailEncodingKey: "UTF-8",
        LanguageLocaleKey: "en_US"
    });
```

This user object is then passed into org.insert(). But I am getting the following error:

```
{"errorCode":"INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY","body":[{"message":"Cannot create a portal user without contact","errorCode":"INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY","fields":["ContactId"]}],"statusCode":400}
```

I am not sure what to put in for the ContactId field here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve this:

```
// Inserts an sobject and returns promise with the object id (if successful)
function insertSObject(obj) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        org.insert({sobject: obj}).then(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            // return id to the next .then call
            resolve(resp.id)
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error('--> unable to insert sobject');
            console.error('--> ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            throw err;
        });
    });
}

function insertAccount(accountName) {
    console.log('attempting to insert account');
    var acct = nforce.createSObject('Account', {
        Name: accountName
    });
    return insertSObject(acct);
}

function insertContact(firstName, lastName, accountId) {
    console.log('attempting to insert contact');
    var contact = nforce.createSObject('Contact', {
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName,
        AccountId: accountId 
    });
    return insertSObject(contact);
}

function insertCommunityUser(firstName, lastName, alias, username, email, nickname, contactId) {
    console.log('attempting to insert user');
    var user = nforce.createSObject('User', {
        FirstName: firstName,
        LastName: lastName,
        Alias: alias,
        Username: username,
        Email: email,
        CommunityNickname: nickname,
        ContactId: contactId,
        ProfileId: "00e36000000YIZ6AAO",  // ProfileId for the Customer Community User profile
        TimeZoneSidKey: "America/New_York",
        LocaleSidKey: "en_US",
        EmailEncodingKey: "UTF-8",
        LanguageLocaleKey: "en_US"
    });
    return insertSObject(user);
}

insertAccount("AnotherAccount1").then(function(id) {
            return insertContact("Adam", "Murphy", id);
        }).then(function(id) {
            return insertCommunityUser("Another", "User", "au1", "au1@test.com", "abc@gmail.com", "aunick", id);
        }).then(function(id) {
            console.log("Successfully inserted userid " + id);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Failed to insert community user. Err " + err);
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

you can not create community user without contact id below is the code to create a community user

```
Id profileId = [select id from profile where name='Partner Community User'].id;


Account objAcc = new Account(name ='Test Account');
insert objAcc; 

Contact objContact = new Contact(LastName ='testCon',AccountId = objAcc.Id);
insert objContact;  

User user = new User(alias = 'TestUser', email='test123@test.com',
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
        localesidkey='en_US', profileid = profileId, country='United States',IsActive =true,
        ContactId = objContact.Id,
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='tester@123.com');

insert user;
```