# Apex Test Class with if/else statement for profile

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to reach 100% test coverage for the following code, currently it's 88%. I was able to figure out the first part, but I don't know if I have to use a runAs() method to run that code with that specific profile, I am new to apex, kindly seeking your help, thank you.

```
public class StudentCheckController {
    public List<Class__c> classes{get; set;}
    String dayFormat = 'MM/DD';
    public Id classId{get; set;}
    public string userEmail{get;set;}
    public string userProfile;

    public StudentCheckController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        userEmail = UserInfo.getUserEmail();
        userProfile = UserInfo.getProfileId();
        System.debug(userProfile);
        getClasses();

    }
    public void getClasses() {
        Id cohortRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.class__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Cohort').getRecordTypeId();

        System.debug(cohortRecordTypeId);
        // Limit visibility to SSS community user
        if(userProfile != '00a7i000000dSK9OOL') {
            
            classes = [ SELECT
                id,
                name,
                class_nights__c,
                start_date__c,
                end_date__c,
                status__c,
                class__c,
                instructor__r.email
                FROM class__c WHERE RecordTypeId = :cohortRecordTypeId AND status__c = 'Active'];
                System.debug(classes);

        } else {
            classes = [ SELECT
                id,
                name,
                class_nights__c,
                start_date__c,
                end_date__c,
                status__c,
                class__c,
                instructor__r.email
                FROM class__c WHERE  RecordTypeId = :cohortRecordTypeId AND status__c = 'Active' AND instructor__r.email = :userEmail];
                System.debug(classes);

        }
    }

    public Pagereference newPage() {
        // Pagereference pf = new Pagereference('/apex/StudentList?id=' + classId);
        Pagereference pf = new Pagereference('https://armhat.force.com/coordinatorportal/StudentList?id=' + classId);
        return pf;
    }
}
```

The test class:

```
@isTest

public class StudentCheckControllerTest {
    static testMethod void testGetClassesNotEqualToProfile(){
        class__c newClass = new class__c(name = 'Test Class', class_nights__c = 'Monday / Wednesday', start_date__c = date.today() - 10, end_date__c = date.today() + 45);
        insert newClass;
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(newClass);
        StudentCheckController pc = new StudentCheckController(sc);
        pc.userEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
        pc.newPage();
        pc.userEmail = 'dreyes@armhat.com';
        pc.getClasses();
    }
```

Comment: In your unit test you need to create a user with a profile that meets your criteria, then do runAs with that user in order to execute your method.

Comment: I'd also look into using sharing rules for what you want to do vs. if branching based on profile.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCheng

Comment: Thank you @willard

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest form it would look something like this:

```
Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Id='00a7i000000dSK9OOL']; 

User u = new User(Alias = 'testUser', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', 
    EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
    LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = p.Id, 
    TimeZoneSidKey='America/New_York', UserName='testUser@example.com');

System.runas(u) {
    // Your test code here that must run as a specific profile.
}
```

Things to consider:

1. Avoid hard coding the Profile ID. When you move your tests between orgs it will change and break your tests and code.
2. Along a similar line - when running a SOQL query for the Profile, what should happen if it isn't found? Right now the code assumes there will always be exactly one match.
3. `userProfile` could be kept as an `Id` rather than a `string`

Comment: Thank you @Daniel
Now i received an error: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Cannot create a portal user without contact: [ContactId]

Is this because the profile is a community user?

Comment: @Abara The answer to [Error in creating Customer Community User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/106154/102) shows an example of inserting the Contact and then using that for the `User.ContactId` field when creating the User record.

Comment: This is very helpful @Daniel after grabbing the ContactId, it gave me another error which specifies that I have to give the running user a role, after setting that up it's working now and test coverage is 100%, thank you very much for your help!